# Why can't I move a file from ~/process.desktop to ~/.config/autostart/?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that simply downloads a package, installs it, then it shoots the "process.desktop" to ~/.config/autostart to add it to XFCE's startup processes.

Everything works but moving the process.desktop to ~/.config/autostart/

Here is my code:

```
mv ~/process.desktop ~/.config/autostart/
```

It returns this error:

```
mv: cannot stat '/username/process.desktop' : No such file or directory
```

Note, the download goes to /home/username/ and it is installed [successfully] there. process.desktop is also in /home/username/

Thanks for any insight, this is the last component of my script I have to fix!

Comment: What is the output of `echo $HOME`?  Is is somehow `/username` by accident?

Answer (score 1):

Weird - you would certainly expect `~` to expand to `/home/username`.

If one thing doesn't work, try another:

```
mv $HOME/process.desktop $HOME/.config/autostart
```

Question:

- Are you sure you want to replace the existing autostart with the new file, rather than, say, adding the new file to the end of the existing autostart file?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, Jonathan. I am currently testing this new syntax now. Also, to answer your question, autostart is a directory. It is full of *processname*.desktop files.

Comment: Dang, no luck. In the terminal it calls me .desktop file "process.desktop" but in thunar, it calls Process_Start which is a title I gave it in the code...? Which should I use?

Comment: `~` should expand to the same thing as `$HOME`; more likely `$HOME` is messed up.

Comment: oh dang, ~/.config/autostart does not exist... it's gone, out of thin air. I did ls -a and it removed itself. Is there I can add it? I'd imagine a simple if statement checking for it and if its not there adding it would work, but does that mess with the installation at all?

Comment: @bourneSH12: You could do `[ ! -e ~/.config/autostart ] && mkdir ~/.config/autostart` to create it if it doesn't already exist (`[` is an alias for the `test` builtin, see `help test`).

Comment: Thanks for the input, Adam. Would this elinate my need for the if fi conditional statement then?

Comment: Update, the code DID make the directory and all is well with that but the .desktop file still didn't move over... do you think this is a permissions thing? I know as a fact you cannot drag and drop files into /autostart/ ... is there a way I can alter my code to force that file to go into that dir or make the user be root when they execute my script? Thanks so much btw!

Comment: `set -vx` is the shell debugging mode. You'll see each line/block of code, then a separate set of line(s) that show how all the variables are expanded. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The tilde path component expands to the *current* value of $HOME.  An example under bash:

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/user
$ echo ~
/home/user
$ HOME=/tmp
$ echo ~
/tmp
```

Have you edited the value of $HOME?  Is it possible that you created this account with the wrong home directory path?  You can check that by:

```
grep username /etc/passwd
```

or

```
finger username
```

If that is the case, you can fix it with the usermod command or just edit /etc/passwd directly.

```
sudo usermod -d /home/username username
```